# react-native-firebase realtime database .ref doesn't work

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I can't read or write into my database, so I was trying to figure out the problem.

When I run `console.log(database().ref("/users/123"));`
I get `"null/users/123"`

But when I try this with firestore `console.log(firestore().doc("users/" + userId));`
I get a long message `{"_documentPath": {"_parts": ["users", "Gz7eG1y7qWX6Q9gijSPDlcLcZop1"]},` ...

When I run `console.log(database());`
I get a long message `{"_app": {"_automaticDataCollectionEnabled": true, "_deleteApp": [Function bound deleteApp],` ...

From this I assume that my firebase setup is correct, there should be a problem with the ref function.

Could you guys help?

I use    `"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.0.0", "@react-native-firebase/database": "^12.0.0", "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.0.0", "react-native": "0.63.4",`

Comment: Please try this firebase.database().ref("/users/123")

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue nothing execute try,catch,then and when I console its give me null and when I use onChildAdded it give me My data. after some search I found mistake it was my Database Url I am using database() but I created my database other than an 'us-central1' default database,

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

 const reference = database().ref('/users/123');
 //not work for me
  import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const reference = firebase
.app()
.database('https://<databaseName>.<region>.firebasedatabase.app/') //my dbUrl
 .ref('/users/123');
 // it work
```

you can read on [RNfirebase Docs](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage) for more detail. I hope it help someone else